# Need help putting $-Y^{\prime\prime} - \mu Y^{\prime} = 0$ into Sturm-Liouville form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

This question is related to the question I asked in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033117/can-this-problem-be-solved-with-eigenfunction-expansion-thought-it-could-then).

I'm trying to find an integrating factor or some way to turn $-Y^{\prime\prime}(y) - \mu Y^{\prime}(y) = 0$ into Sturm-Liouville form.

On that post, someone suggested the substitution $Y(y) = e^{-\mu y}Z(y)$.

I differentiated $e^{-\mu y} Z(y)$ twice, substituted the expressions I obtained for both $Y^{\prime}$ and $Y^{\prime \prime}$ into the equation and ended up with $-e^{-\mu y} Z^{\prime \prime} (y) - \mu e^{-\mu y} Z^{\prime}(y) + 2  = 0$.

Now, recall that a Sturm-Liouville problem is of the form $-[p(x)u^{\prime}(x)]^{\prime} + q(x)u(x) = \mu r(x) u(x)$ or $\mathbf{-p^{\prime}(x)u^{\prime}(x) - p(x) u^{\prime \prime}(x) + q(x) u(x) = \mu r(x) u(x)}$), and we need for both $p(x)$ and $r(x)$ to be strictly positve on the interval we're dealing with (here it's [0,1]).

So, now I no longer have $r(x)$ strictly positive.

What am I doing wrong?? I'm feeling very frustrated.

Could someone please help me?? And if it's not possible to write this problem in Sturm-Liouville form, could you let me know that? Thank you. I'm really struggling with this.

Comment: is $Y$ just a function of the real variable ? or is it some kind of operator on differentiable functions ? and is $\mu$ only a real number too?

Comment: @Marsan, $Y$ is a function of $y$. $Z$ is also a function of $y$.

Comment: yes but is $y$ a function or a real number ?? if it is your problem is trivial since the solution to such equation is simply $y \mapsto -\frac{e^{-\mu y}}{\mu} + Ay + B$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: @Marsan $y$ is a real number and $0 < y < 1$. Sorry I forgot to include that piece of info. This is actually a follow-up type of question related to the question I asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033117/can-this-problem-be-solved-with-eigenfunction-expansion-thought-it-could-then

Comment: @Marsan, bascially, the ODE in $Y$ resulted from performing separation of variables on a PDE in $x$ and $y$ where also $0 < x < 1$

Comment: But then simply $Y(y) = \frac{-e^{-\mu y}}{\mu} + Ay +B$ where $A$ and B are constants. It is a linear differential equation in $Y'$... and then you integrate

Comment: @Marsan I know it's not hard to solve that way. But the question I'm working on asked me to solve it this way instead.

Comment: @Marsan actually I think I've got it: $Y(y) = e^{- \mu y /2} Z(y)$. I'm gonna try that and maybe answer my own question ;)

Comment: The eigenvalue parameter $\mu$--if that's what it is--cannot multiply the derivative. It must multiply the function, not the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach:
$$
-Y''-\mu Y'=0\\
\Downarrow\\
\frac{Y''}{Y'}=-\mu\\
\Downarrow\\
\log(Y')=\eta-\mu y\\
\Downarrow\\
Y'=e^{\eta-\mu y}\\
\Downarrow\\
Y=a+b e^{-\mu y}
$$